# How to use Vue.js inside Django?

Tags: django, django-models, vuejs2

Given this  model in Django 2,

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

and in my view

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

How can I access the context inside index.html so that Vue.js can consume that data?

Answer (score 0):

```
V-for="context in contexts"
${context.fieldname}
```

Fieldwould be your model names using for you will have list of all also